# How to implement deletion of user?

Tags: java, sql, database-design

I’m developing my test project that presents library. As far as I develop it, I meet questions continuously.

Could you help me with one of them?

My model design includes User and LeasingHistory entities, so when user borrows a book LeasingHistory table fills with corresponding record.

```
create table USER
(
 ID BIGINT not null serial primary key,
 ADDRESS VARCHAR(255) not null,
 DOCUMENT_ID VARCHAR(255) not null,
 FIRST_NAME VARCHAR(255) not null,
 SUR_NAME VARCHAR(255) not null
);

create table LEASING_HISTORY
(
 ID BIGINT not null serial primary key,
 BOOK_INSTANCE_ID BIGINT not null,
 USER_ID BIGINT not null,
 START_DATE DATE(10),
 ARRANGED_END_DATE DATE(10),
 ACTUAL_END_DATE DATE(10),
 foreign key (BOOK_INSTANCE_ID) references BOOK_INSTANCE,
 foreign key (USER_ID) references USER
);
```

Now I have to implement user deletion. How should I do it? How is it implemented in Google, Facebook or in StackOverFlow?

I don’t think that delete orphans is appropriate strategy in this case because history shouldn’t be cleaned up.

I suppose I can add isActive field to User table. In this case I can clear personal info and assign `isActive = false` when user presses “Delete Account” button.

What are your thought about it?

UPDATE:
I think that an user should have a possibility to recover his account thus in this case @killjoy option is better. Can you check me, do I understand it correctly? I've introduced additional table `UserInternalData` and in case of user deletion I will clear all data (besides `id`) from `User` entity and set `isDeleted` to true and `dateStamp` to current date in 'UserInternalData'

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Getter
@EqualsAndHashCode
@ToString
class Person {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    private String firstName;

    private String surName;

    @JsonFormat(pattern="yyyy-MM-dd")
    private LocalDate dateOfBirth;

}

@Entity
@NoArgsConstructor
@Getter
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = true)
@ToString(callSuper = true)
public final class User extends Person {

    @Builder
    public User(Long id, String firstName, String surName, LocalDate dateOfBirth, String documentId, String address) {
        super(id, firstName, surName, dateOfBirth);
        this.documentId = documentId;
        this.address = address;
    }

    private String documentId;

    private String address;

}

@Entity
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Builder
@Getter
@EqualsAndHashCode
@ToString
public final class UserInternalData {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @OneToOne
    private User user;

    boolean isDeleted;

    @JsonFormat(pattern="yyyy-MM-dd")
    private LocalDate dateStamp;

}
```

Am I right?

Comment: By law, you may be required to actually delete the data. Learn about GDPR.

Comment: I can set to null all columns that contain personal info and leave only id and isActive

Comment: I would separate all personal info into a separate table with a one-to-one relationship, then you could just delete the rows. You can keep things like sign in info (SALTED HASH!) and user id in another table

Comment: *How is it implemented in Google, Facebook or in StackOverFlow?* Good luck finding one person from Google, Facebook **and** StackOverflow who can answer this.

Comment: Sign in info? If I delete user I should release email and nickname and let a user sign up once more again with the same email. So sign in info is personal info too

Comment: StackOverflow database is publicly available if you want to [check it out](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/new). For example, here's a query on the StackOverflow Users table: https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/857412

Comment: @JacobH: That isn't the internal database schema.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A few approaches to consider.

1. Add an `isActive` column (or equivalently, an `isDeleted` column) to the `USER` table. Clear (or set) the bit when the user is deleted. You probably also want to wipe out other sensitive info. This leaves open the possibility of reactivating deleted users in the future.
2. Replace the `USER_ID` field in all of the affected rows in `LEASING_HISTORY` with a special reserved ID that represents a deleted user (possibly with a name like `"Deleted User"`).
3. As per @killjoy, normalize the two tables by adding a third table that relates `USER_ID` to `BOOK_INSTANCE_ID`, and remove the `USER_ID` column from `LEASING_HISTORY`. Then you can simply delete the affected rows from this third table without losing the book leasing history.

**Addendum**

On second thought, (3) might not be such a good approach. The idea was to separate the `USER_ID` foreign key out into a separate table, but this does not solve the dangling deleted foreign key problem.

Perhaps a more workable approach is:

4. Do not constrain `USER_ID` to be a foreign key. That way, you can safely delete `USER` rows without needing any cleanup at all. Of course, you still need to insure referential integrity (programmatically) at the time you create each new `LEASING_HISTORY` row.

I prefer (1) because you are not deleting any user history, just the sensitive user info.

Comment: Thank you for this answer! Could I ask you to extend 3rd point?

Comment: Thank you! I would like to notice that 4th point complicates hibernate's ease-of-use